# From where i can get worsite sdk?

Tags: imanage, worksite-sdk

I have several issues related with "iManage worksite web". I surfed for a few days at web but could't find "Worksite SDK". As i'm understand this SDK is absent in free download. And i don't understand why.
Is any body know where i can download this SDK? Or anybody can send to me it by email?
Thanks.

Comment: Asking for software/downloads is EXPLICITLY off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDK is a licensed product from IManage. You need to speak to your IManage support vendor to get an appropriate licence. They can then give you access to download the SDK from their support site.

If you're having specific problems with worksite or worksite web, post a separate question specifically targeted at those problems.